# how to Open source code from android apk created through adobe Air( coded in flash)?

Tags: java, flash, class, adobe, apk

I am trying to generate the source code from apk (which is created by adobe air, which is actually coded in flash)but It generates with no java classes and no images in res folder. The app actually a game app which has a 50 images in it. Can any body suggest me that, how to get the converted flash code into java files and the resource through the apk. I would be obliged   if any suggests. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it's created using Adobe Air, you are not going to find any java classes or images in the res folder. It is using ActionScript and probably embedded images.

Comment: then how to view the source code in android?

Answer (score 0):

umm... you need to disassemble the APK. Did you check inside for .dex or .class files?

If yes, you might be able to use something like DJ Java Decompiler on those .class files. But android uses .DEX files instead of .class and .APK instead of .JARs.

Comment: I used DJ Java Decompiler but it creates air and com files with a few  java classes, but these java classes are not the script classes where the gaming code resides in flash.. please help me.

Comment: does any one has the solution?